# Web3 Function Calls are very slow !

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I am running a local geth node (--fast --rpc) and executing the following code in a local Nodejs program:

https://gist.github.com/admazzola/79daee3b41e47596e36286464b1d98dd

Strangely, it works but that loop runs extremely slow and each function call takes about one whole second to resolve.  Once it gets up in the 2 or 3 thousands it usually locks up or freezes up and I don't know why that is.  Is there a better way to pull all of this data and store it in a dictionary or is this the best way?  Why is it so slow if I am just gathering local data?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a better way to pull all of this data and store it in a dictionary or is this the best way?

It would almost certainly be faster to parse the data directly from the `.ldb` files in the `chaindata` directory, and then cache it. To do that would require you to parse it, which itself requires knowledge of how the data is stored.

If you're using Node.js, you could take a look at *["Exploring Ethereum's state trie with Node.js"](https://wanderer.github.io/ethereum/nodejs/code/2014/05/21/using-ethereums-tries-with-node/)*. (Node.js is probably not the best language to use for this.) Note that the code in the tutorial is slightly out of date. I've included a tweaked working version below.

```
var levelup = require('levelup');
var rlp = require('rlp');
var trie = require('merkle-patricia-tree');
var db = levelup('chaindata');

// The genesis state root.
var stateRoot = 
  'd7f8974fb5ac78d9ac099b9ad5018bedc2ce0a72dad1827a1709da30580f0544';

// ERROR: AssertionError: Invalid root length. Roots are 32 bytes
var stateTrie = new trie(db, stateRoot);

// Note: We're doing everything using binary encoding.
db.get(new Buffer(stateRoot, 'hex'), {
  encoding: 'binary'
}, function (err, value) {
  console.log("Printing the entry for the State Root")
  var decoded = rlp.decode(value);
  console.log(decoded);
});

// Gav's address.
var gav = new Buffer('8a40bfaa73256b60764c1bf40675a99083efb075', 'hex');

trie.get(gav, function (err, val) {
  console.log("Printing the contents of Gav's address")
  var decoded = rlp.decode(val);
  console.log(decoded);
});
```

Comment: the stateRoot should have 0x prefix to avoid AssertionError: Invalid root length. Roots are 32 bytes

Comment: Also the address needs to be hashed before looking it up in the trie. A working example is here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40254/getting-complete-state-of-an-smart-contract/40280#40280 :)

Comment: Thanks! Let me poke around and remind myself how this works. There's almost certainly a problem with the above code using the old version of LevelUp for a start... (as in, it wouldn't work now with the newer versions of LevelUp and LevelDown anyway). I'll defer to your code from now on :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to  get the addresses much faster without using call! I don't really understand the merkle tree data retrieval but I will look into that too.  Here is the really fast data-grabbing code (asychronous):

```
 var PunkContract = web3.eth.contract(contract_abi);
     var contractInstance = PunkContract.at('0xb47e3cd837dDF8e4c57F05d70Ab865de6e193BBB');




        let number_of_punks_found = 0;
        var punk_id = 0;

          for(punk_id=0;punk_id<100;punk_id++)
          {

            let temp_punk_id = punk_id;
              var punks = contractInstance.punkIndexToAddress(punk_id, function(err, res){
                  console.log(temp_punk_id);
                  console.log(res);

                  punkOwners[temp_punk_id] = res;
                  number_of_punks_found++;
              });


          }
```

and here is the whole codebase for you all to use as reference:

https://github.com/admazzola/punkpipeline

That is a nodejs bot that continuously reads and caches smart contract storage data from geth.  It stores the data in memory and in a JSON file.  It has a simple JSONRPC interface of its own so that other local bots can access the cached data in custom ways.